# Get SWT element's parent Part

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I need to reference the `Part` object that created an SWT element. The `Part` is creating a `Label` in `Part`'s `@PostConstruct` like that (e4):

```
public class SomePart {
    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(Composite parent) {
        ...
        Label someLabel = new Label(parent);
        ...
    }
}
```

Need to get part that created `someLabel` like this:

```
(SomePart) someLabel.getMyParentPartPlease()
```

Also need to get such reference in RCP 3.x, but I will be realy happy to get help on any RCP version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set the `Part` on the `Widget` in question in it's data field, which allows clients to set arbitary data on the object?

```
public class SomePart {
    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(Composite parent) {
        ...
        Label someLabel = new Label(parent);
        someLabel.setData(this);
        ...
    }
}
```

Then later:

```
SomePart part = (SomePart) someLabel.getData();
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But, actualy, I don't manage Part's code. I'm trying to reference Part from my SWT listeners. Do you have any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: @Oroboros102 I do not, off the top of my head, unfortunately.  I edited your question a bit to clarify that.  I will give it further thought, but hopefully somebody else has some idea as well.

Comment: Oh, the worst part of all RCP for me is trying to connect SWT object with RCP (pass data, get it and such). Every time that ends with massive usage of `.setData(...)`, which looks ugly. Now I think, that I just don't catch the architecture of the RCP.

Comment: setData() method is ugly design. First of all, why do you need to reference Part from Label()? I just want to understand use-case.

Comment: @sambireddy "Ugly design"?  Care to clarify?

Comment: setData() method and keeping references to other Objects that are irrelevant for the model of the Label is not a good idea, I think. it could lead to memory leaks. Thats why I am questioning the question!.

Comment: @sambireddy I bet, my use case is really rare. It is about security. Parts have security contexts, and Listeners on SWT elements must obtain it somehow. AFAIK, SWT elements are destroyed together with parts, so there should be no memleaks.